# SVG inlined in CSS works in Chrome/Edge but not in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I have the following code to display icons. The GitHub icon doesn't work on Firefox but works on Chrome and Edge. Strangely, the Google icon works on all browsers!

```
.github-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 1792 1792' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' %3E%3Cpath fill='#fff' d='M1664 896q0 251-146.5 451.5t-378.5 277.5q-27 5-39.5-7t-12.5-30v-211q0-97-52-142 57-6 102.5-18t94-39 81-66.5 53-105 20.5-150.5q0-121-79-206 37-91-8-204-28-9-81 11t-92 44l-38 24q-93-26-192-26t-192 26q-16-11-42.5-27t-83.5-38.5-86-13.5q-44 113-7 204-79 85-79 206 0 85 20.5 150t52.5 105 80.5 67 94 39 102.5 18q-40 36-49 103-21 10-45 15t-57 5-65.5-21.5-55.5-62.5q-19-32-48.5-52t-49.5-24l-20-3q-21 0-29 4.5t-5 11.5 9 14 13 12l7 5q22 10 43.5 38t31.5 51l10 23q13 38 44 61.5t67 30 69.5 7 55.5-3.5l23-4q0 38 .5 89t.5 54q0 18-13 30t-40 7q-232-77-378.5-277.5t-146.5-451.5q0-209 103-385.5t279.5-279.5 385.5-103 385.5 103 279.5 279.5 103 385.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: dimgray;
}

.google-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'  viewBox='-60 -60 710.117 710.117' %3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M516.375,255v-76.5h-51V255h-76.5v51h76.5v76.5h51V306h76.5v-51H516.375z M320.025,341.7l-28.051-20.4%0Ac-10.2-7.649-20.399-17.85-20.399-35.7s12.75-33.15,25.5-40.8c33.15-25.5,66.3-53.55,66.3-109.65c0-53.55-33.15-84.15-51-99.45%0Ah43.35l30.6-35.7h-158.1c-112.2,0-168.3,71.4-168.3,147.9c0,58.65,45.9,122.4,127.5,122.4h20.4c-2.55,7.65-10.2,20.4-10.2,33.15%0Ac0,25.5,10.2,35.7,22.95,51c-35.7,2.55-102,10.2-150.45,40.8c-45.9,28.05-58.65,66.3-58.65,94.35%0Ac0,58.65,53.55,114.75,168.3,114.75c137.7,0,204.001-76.5,204.001-150.449C383.775,400.35,355.725,372.3,320.025,341.7z%0AM126.225,109.65c0-56.1,33.15-81.6,68.85-81.6c66.3,0,102,89.25,102,140.25c0,66.3-53.55,79.05-73.95,79.05%0AC159.375,247.35,126.225,168.3,126.225,109.65z M218.024,568.65c-84.15,0-137.7-38.25-137.7-94.351c0-56.1,51-73.95,66.3-81.6%0Ac33.15-10.2,76.5-12.75,84.15-12.75s12.75,0,17.85,0c61.2,43.35,86.7,61.2,86.7,102C335.324,530.4,286.875,568.65,218.024,568.65z%0A'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. # should be replaced with %23